# Using jQuery to set CSS "width" property as the text value of a siblings child

Tags: jquery

I'd like to set the with of each `.progress-bar-percentage` using the text value of his closest `percentage-value`

I've tried

```
$('.progress-bar-percentage').css('width', $(this).siblings('.percentage-script').find('.percentage-value').text());
```

But with no luck

```
<div class="progress-bar-total">
    <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
    <div class="percentage-script">
        <div class="percentage-value">50%</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-total">
    <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
    <div class="percentage-script">
        <div class="percentage-value">25%</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-total">
    <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
    <div class="percentage-script">
        <div class="percentage-value">10%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
$('.progress-bar-percentage').css('width', function() {
  return $(this).siblings('.percentage-script').find('.percentage-value').text()
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.progress-bar-percentage').css('width', function() {
  return $(this).siblings('.percentage-script').find('.percentage-value').text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-total">
  <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
  <div class="percentage-script">
    <div class="percentage-value">50%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-total">
  <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
  <div class="percentage-script">
    <div class="percentage-value">25%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-total">
  <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
  <div class="percentage-script">
    <div class="percentage-value">10%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```